# how to get each column of values as array directly, and without using pluck laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transpose

hi trying to get the values of two columns as arrays, something like this

```php
"result": {
    "time": [1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
    "values": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

i was able to do it using:

```php
$result['result'] = DB::table(TimeSignal::getTableName())->select([
    'value',
    DB::raw("(time * 0.001) as time")
])
->where('trip_id', $trip->id)
->where('signal_type_id', $timeSignalType->id)
->orderBy('time', 'asc')
->get();
```

then:

```php
$timeSignalData = $result['result'];
$result['result']['time'] = $timeSignalData->pluck('time');
$result['result']['values'] = $timeSignalData->pluck('value');
```

but the pluck function taking so much time to make the objects as array is their some way to do this faster or can we do it form the query directly.

Comment: As a side note... `pluck` shouldn't really be slow. Are you sure the query isn't the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can solve your problems with a macro I found in [Refactoring to Collections](https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/).

```php
Collection::macro('transpose', function () {
    $items = array_map(function (...$items) {
        return $items;
    }, ...$this->values());
    return new static($items);
});
```

Visually it's something like this:

```
[1,2]                 [1,3,5]
[3,4] => transpose => [2,4,6]
[5,6]
```

Get the values in a Collection

```php
$queryCollection = DB::table(TimeSignal::getTableName())->select([
    'value',
    DB::raw("(time * 0.001) as time")
])
->where('trip_id', $trip->id)
->where('signal_type_id', $timeSignalType->id)
->orderBy('time', 'asc')
->get();
```

This is how it looks so far

```php
# dump($queryCollection)
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
    all: [
        {
            +"value": 5,
            +"time": 1,
        },
        {
            +"value": 6,
            +"time": 2,
        },
        {
            +"value": 7,
            +"time": 4,
        },
        {
            +"value": 8,
            +"time": 5,
        },
        {
            +"value": 9,
            +"time": 6,
        },
        ...
    ],
}
```

Map every row to an Array...

```php
$rows = $queryCollection->map(function($item) {
    return collect($item)->toArray();
}));
```

Now it looks like this

```php
# dump($rows)
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
    all: [
        [
            "value": 5,
            "time": 1,
        ],
        [
            "value": 6,
            "time": 2,
        ],
        [
            "value": 7,
            "time": 4,
        ],
        [
            "value": 8,
            "time": 5,
        ],
        [
            "value": 9,
            "time": 6,
        ],
        ...
    ],
}
```

Now we transpose it.

```
$rows = $rows->transpose()
```

Which gives us

```php
# dump($rows)

Illuminate\Support\Collection {
    all: [
        [
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            4,
            5,
            6,
        ],
    ]
}
```

And finally, we add the keys:

```php
$result = collect(['values', 'time'])->combine($rows)
```

Which gives us, finally:

```php
# dump($result)
Illuminate\Support\Collection {
    all: [
        "values" => [
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9
        ],
        "time" => [
            1,
            2,
            4,
            5,
            6,
        ],
    ]
}
```

```
# dump($result['time'])
[
    1,
    2,
    4,
    5,
    6,
]
```

```
# dump($result['values'])
[
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
]
```

Less steps:

```php
$queryCollection = DB::table(TimeSignal::getTableName())->select([
    'value',
    DB::raw("(time * 0.001) as time")
])
->where('trip_id', $trip->id)
->where('signal_type_id', $timeSignalType->id)
->orderBy('time', 'asc')
->get();

$result = collect(['values', 'time'])->combine($queryCollection->map(function ($item) {
    return collect($item)->toArray();
})->transpose());
```

Comment: hi @IGP, thanks for your time, i tried the code and it's give the wanted json format, but it's not faster than pluck i need something faster than pluck, pluck take around 4.5 sec and your code take 6.5

Comment: Either your database is gigantic or your server has some issues. Which laravel version are you using? If you're on 6.x, you could try LazyCollections.

Comment: it's 5.8, and i don't think my database has any issues cause i run the query inside pg-admin and it's takes only milliseconds

Comment: The thing is, running those queries in Laravel means creating a collection containing every single result. That takes some memory, specially if the collection is very big.

Comment: yup i know it's big data that need  some memory, but i was looking for something to do it faster with less memory, and i'm using timescale-db with PostgreSQL database so i can speed up the processes, and the thing that the laravel query is fast, but the problem in the pluck function that take like 4 5 sec to reformat the data, so this basically the problem, so i was looking to format the data directly form the query if i can to avoid using collocation and pluck